# How to install a driver on Network controller: Intel Corporation WiMAX/WiFi Link 5150?

Tags: debian, driver

I use debian 8 and gnom. I can not install the drivers for the wifi. Please help, I'm not an experienced user, so please write everything in detail.

I use:

Cinnamon: 2.2.16

Core Linux: 3.16.0-4.amd64

Now all of the `syslog` about the `wifi`:

```
Dec 22 11:50:57 localhost kernel: [   10.142589] Intel(R) Wireless WiFi driver for Linux, in-tree:
Dec 22 11:50:57 localhost kernel: [   10.142745] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: can't disable ASPM; OS doesn't have ASPM control
Dec 22 11:50:57 localhost kernel: [   10.142811] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: irq 48 for MSI/MSI-X
Dec 22 11:50:57 localhost kernel: [   10.153523] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: firmware: failed to load iwlwifi-5150-2.ucode (-2)
Dec 22 11:50:57 localhost kernel: [   10.153574] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Direct firmware load failed with error -2
Dec 22 11:50:57 localhost kernel: [   10.153576] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Falling back to user helper
Dec 22 11:50:57 localhost kernel: [   10.488382] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: firmware: failed to load iwlwifi-5150-1.ucode (-2)
Dec 22 11:50:57 localhost kernel: [   10.488440] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Direct firmware load failed with error -2
Dec 22 11:50:57 localhost kernel: [   10.488443] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Falling back to user helper
Dec 22 11:50:57 localhost kernel: [   10.514768] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: no suitable firmware found!
Dec 22 11:50:59 localhost NetworkManager[487]: <info> rfkill0: found WiFi radio killswitch (at /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.0/PNP0C09:00/VPC2004:00/rfkill/rfkill0) (platform driver ideapad_acpi)
Dec 22 11:50:59 localhost NetworkManager[487]: <info> WiFi hardware radio set enabled
Dec 22 11:50:59 localhost NetworkManager[487]: <info> Loaded device plugin: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/NetworkManager/libnm-device-plugin-wifi.so
Dec 22 11:50:59 localhost NetworkManager[487]: <info> WiFi enabled by radio killswitch; enabled by state file
Dec 22 11:50:59 localhost NetworkManager[487]: <info> WWAN enabled by radio killswitch; enabled by state file
Dec 22 11:50:59 localhost NetworkManager[487]: <info> WiMAX enabled by radio killswitch; enabled by state file
```

Comment: What can you see on logfile? Which you have kernel version?

Comment: @PrzemysławJagielski Added kernel version. How to get the logfile?

Comment: In /var/log you have syslog, etc. @EmptyMan

Comment: and for that minus issue?

Comment: @PrzemysławJagielski i added cod in syslog

Comment: What is the output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A2`? Please [edit here](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/41280342/edit)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the wifi working on *Intel Corporation WiMAX/WiFi Link 5150* you should follow the steps described on [debian-wiki](https://wiki.debian.org/iwlwifi):

Add a `non-free` component to `/etc/apt/sources.list`, open the terminal and run the following commands:

```
sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list
```

add the following line:

```
deb http://httpredir.debian.org/debian/ jessie main contrib non-free
```

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>o</kbd> then press <kbd>Enter</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> +<kbd>X</kbd>

Update and install `iwlwifi` driver:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install firmware-iwlwifi
```

Re-Load the driver:

```
sudo modprobe -r iwlwifi && sudo modprobe iwlwifi
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, but on the last line of your code displays: 
`bash: modprode: команда не найдена`